# R: how to summarize by year below each row

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I got the dataframe below and the function that summarize my dataframe

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df_so = data.frame(Ano=c(2017, 2017, 2017, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2019, 2019), 
                   Metodo=c("x","y","x","x","x","x","z","x"))
df_so %>%
  group_by(Ano, Metodo) %>%
  tally()%>%
  rename(quantidade = n)%>%
  summarise(Ano = c("", Ano), Metodo = c('Total', Metodo),  
            across(quantidade, ~c(sum(., na.rm = TRUE), .)))
```

So I have the result:

```
  Ano    Metodo quantidade
  <chr>  <chr>       <int>
1 ""     Total           3
2 "2017" x               2
3 "2017" y               1
4 ""     Total           3
5 "2018" x               3
6 ""     Total           2
7 "2019" x               1
8 "2019" z               1
```

However, I would like:

```
  Ano    Metodo quantidade
  <chr>  <chr>       <int>
1 "2017" x               2
2 "2017" y               1
3 "2017" Total           3
4 "2018" x               3
5 "2018" Total           3
6 "2019" x               1
7 "2019" z               1  
8 "2019" Total           2
```

How can I get this kind of result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After your `tally`, you can add an extra `summarise` row per group using `group_modify` and `bind_rows`.

Since you have a character `Ano` column in your desired output, I added an extra `mutate` at the end to achieve that.

```r
library(dplyr)

df_so %>% 
  group_by(Ano, Metodo) %>% 
  tally() %>% 
  group_modify(~bind_rows(.x, summarize(.x, Metodo = "Total", n = sum(n)))) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(Ano = as.character(Ano))

# A tibble: 8 × 3
  Ano   Metodo     n
  <chr> <chr>  <int>
1 2017  x          2
2 2017  y          1
3 2017  Total      3
4 2018  x          3
5 2018  Total      3
6 2019  x          1
7 2019  z          1
8 2019  Total      2
```

Answer (score 3):

**1)** We can use `adorn_totals` from the janitor package:

```
library(dplyr)
library(janitor)

df_so %>%
  count(Ano, Metodo, name = "quant") %>%
  reframe(adorn_totals(across()), .by = Ano)
```

giving:

```
# A tibble: 8 x 3
    Ano Metodo quant
  <dbl> <chr>  <int>
1  2017 x          2
2  2017 y          1
3  2017 Total      3
4  2018 x          3
5  2018 Total      3
6  2019 x          1
7  2019 z          1
8  2019 Total      2
```

**2)** A simple 2d layout could be produced using `table`. No packages are used.

```
addmargins(table(df_so))
```

giving:

```
      Metodo
Ano    x y z Sum
  2017 2 1 0   3
  2018 3 0 0   3
  2019 1 0 1   2
  Sum  6 1 1   8
```

or equivalently with this pipeline

```
df_so |> table() |> addmargins()
```

or in long form:

```
ftable(addmargins(table(df_so)), row.vars = 1:2)
```

giving:

```
Ano  Metodo   
2017 x       2
     y       1
     z       0
     Sum     3
2018 x       3
     y       0
     z       0
     Sum     3
2019 x       1
     y       0
     z       1
     Sum     2
Sum  x       6
     y       1
     z       1
     Sum     8
```

or equivalently with this pipeline

```
df_so |> table() |> addmargins() |> ftable(row.vars = 1:2)
```